# How to count command line arguments in expect script?

Tags: expect

This is my simple expect script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
puts "Argu 1 : [lindex $argv 0]"

Run
---
expect example.expt Testing

Output
------
Argu 1: Tesing
```

I need to count the arguments, which are passed by command line. Like this:

```
expect example.expt 1 2 3 4

I need the script for the following output
Total: 4 arguments
Arg1: 1
Arg2: 2
Arg3: 3
Arg4: 4
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expect` uses [Tcl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) as its scripting language. You're looking for the [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/llength.htm) command:

```
puts "Total: [llength $argv] argument(s)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Late but will be useful i guess.

This prints the number of command line arguments and the arguments list as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

puts "No of Command Line Arguments : [llength $argv]"

puts "Arguments List "
set argsCount [llength $argv];
set i 0
while {$i < $argsCount } {
    puts [lindex $argv $i]
    set i [expr $i+1];
}
```

More details about expect scripting can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378)

Comment: `;` in `set i [expr $i+1];` can be omitted and the whole line replaced with `incr i`